# How can I smooth ConvexHull like an ellipse?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, data-science

I am trying to plot an encircling area in a scatter plot with Matplotlib, and I want to smooth a Convex Hull like an ellipse. Could anyone give me some suggestions?

Here is my code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import patches

midwest = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gitony0101/X4DS/main/data/midwest_filter.csv')

midwest_encircle_data = midwest.query("state=='IN'")

_, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))

g = sns.scatterplot(x='area',
                    y='poptotal',
                    data=midwest,
                    hue='state',
                    palette='tab10',
                    size='popdensity',
                    ax=ax)


def encircle(x, y, ax=None, **kw):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    p = np.stack([x, y], axis=1)
    hull = ConvexHull(p)
    poly = patches.Polygon(xy=p[hull.vertices, :], closed=True, **kw)
    ax.add_patch(poly)


g.set(xlim=(0.0, 0.1),
      ylim=(0, 90000),
      xlabel='Area',
      ylabel='Population',
      title='Bubble Plot with Encircling')

x = midwest_encircle_data['area']
y = midwest_encircle_data['poptotal']

encircle(x, y, ec='k', fc='gold', alpha=0.1, ax=ax)
encircle(x, y, ec='firebrick', fc='none', linewidth=1.5, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Which is the _right way_ to rotate the ellipse? Has it to be simply horizontal? Or rotated by a known angle `theta`?

Comment: [Plot Ellipse with matplotlib.pyplot (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952060/plot-ellipse-with-matplotlib-pyplot-python): The second part of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48409811/7758804), but it doesn't use patch.Ellipse, [Matplotlib patches ellipse angle query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160056/matplotlib-patches-ellipse-angle-query): the question shows how to rotate the ellipse.

Comment: It seems like rotation is non-trivial: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/units/ellipse_with_units.html & https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/confidence_ellipse.html

Comment: @Zephyr Thank you for your reply, I added more details to description of my question.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thank you. I read the article provided by Matplotlib. Those examples plot the confidence interval, while mine is to plot the max values of ranges. I haven't got inspiration from the examples yet, and I don't understand Affine2D well.